# Div Bind issues

Tags: jquery

I have a document where i have disabled the scroll on page by using

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', false);
```

Now i'm loading a page dynamically into a div after click of a button...

```
$('#myContentPage').load('details.html #myCOntentPage');
```

I want to unbind 'touchmove' only from the div #myContentPage after load is finished.
I tried

`$('#myContentPage').bind('touchmove', true);` after page load , but it does not seem to work.

HTML Structure before load

```
<body>
    <div id="header"/>
    <div id="details"/>
    <div id="myContentPage" />
</body>
```

HTML Structure after load

```
<body>
    <div id="header"/>
    <div id="details"/>
    <div id="myContentPage" >
        <div ... />
        <div.... />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10478450/601179).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't detach the `touchmove` event callback form `'#myContentPage'` because it was attached to his parent- `<body>`, Do the best way to fix it is to attach a new handler to `#myContentPage` that will stop Propagation to `<body>` which cancel the event.

```
$('#myContentPage').load('details.html #myCOntentPage', function() {
    $('#myContentPage').bind('touchmove', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation() ;
    }); 
});
```

If that doesn't help (*from some unknown reason*), try this:

```
$('#myContentPage').load('details.html #myCOntentPage', function() {
    $('body').unbind('touchmove');
    $('body').on('touchmove', ':not(#myContentPage)', function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: <fussy>Should be `#myCo` instead of `#myCO`</fussy>

Comment: @NiftyDude. This is his code. but you're probably right. I edited it. Thanks

Comment: @NiftyDude. Actually there was a real problem in my code... But I fixed it by now.

Comment: I didn't even check your code correctness :p, but good thing though, hopefully OP can recheck your answer

Comment: @NiftyDude. You can see the pervious answer at the other guys... couple of mintues later... Anyway, you can't `$('#myContentPage').unbind('touchmove');` because the `touchmove` was attached to the `<body>`... Maybe they'll copy the update as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#myContentPage').off('touchmove'); // if you bind event using `on()`
```

OR

```
 $('#myContentPage').unbind('touchmove');
```

so,

```
$('#myContentPage').load('details.html #myCOntentPage', function() {
    $('#myContentPage').off('touchmove'); 
});
```

Comment: _"The off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()."_

Answer (score 0):

After yor new page is loaded, you can use this  to unbind your previously attached event

```
$('#myContentPage').unbind('touchmove');
```

Comment: thanks everyone but none of the suggestions seems to work i tried unbind,off .. i'm checking it on ipad
i also double checked if that is the proper div and but still could not resolve it :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(ev){
  if ( ev.target.id != "myContentPage"){
    return false;
  }
});
```

Instead of:
     `$('body').bind('touchmove', false);`